# Why are '20, 22' in 'string DB 20, 22 dup('?')' needed?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I've been defining strings with for `DB 20, 22` some time without knowing why:

I read that the first byte is the buffer size and the second holds the number of used bytes for string, but I don't know if both values are mandatory. For example when I define a string and want to point a register to it I have to use +2 to skip these two characters.

```
string DB 20, 22 dup('?')
lea si, string+2
lea si, [string] ; I think this is another alternative
```

That makes me wonder whether if I defined the string without them I could just do `lea si, string`. Is this possible or are both items mandatory? Also when I want to skip a line and move the cursor to the start I do `DB 13, 10` how does the compiler know that 13 isn't the buffer size and 10 the number of characters? I'm probably speaking nonsense but any clarification on these issue will be thanked

Comment: `x dup (y)` is one way of writing "`x` copies of the value `y`".  This appears to me to be a length-prefixed string of 20 '?' characters, if we consider the length a bit off.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing with those strings as there are several methods of representing strings in memory.

Comment: I removed the dup() because it wasn't what I cared about. One of the things I want to know is if there is a way to define the string so I can point to it simply by 'lea si, string'

Comment: "first byte is buffer size..." would be correct if you're using int 21h/0Ah -  dos's buffered input function. If you're not using that interrupt, this does not apply, and you probably don't want those bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a string, then just define it:

```
myString db 'hello, world'
```

And then you can address it as you showed:

```
lea si, myString
```

However, you either need to know how long the string is, or you have to add a terminator character so that the output function knows where to stop. If you want 0-terminated strings, for example:

```
myString db 'hello, world', 0  ; don't forget that terminator
```

Or, you can put the length before the string, which might be what your `20, 22` was:

```
myString db 12, 'hello, world'
```

One byte is good for strings up to 255 characters. If you need to handle strings longer than that, you'll probably want to standardize on two bytes for the string length.

Whichever you choose, your output function will need to know how to handle it.

By the way, if you want length-prefixed strings, you shouldn't hand-code the lengths. Let the assembler figure it out for you:

```
myString db myStringEnd - $
         db 'hello, world'
myStringEnd equ $
```

Comment: I don't really want to prefix the length, I didn't even know I was doing it. If I do this: `string DB 10 dup('?')` I'm not prefixing any lenght am I? Just stating that I want the first 10 characters to be '?'. I don't care about the terminator since I'm not directly printing the string

Comment: `db len, ?, len dup(?)` is very likely an input buffer for DOS `int 21h` / `ah=0Ah` which uses that struct format before the actual data:  http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a.  That could be what's happening here with the read-length byte folded into the `dup(?)` length.

Answer (score 0):

I think "db 20, 22 dup(?)" will actually put the following bytes in memory: 0x14 0x00 0x00 0x00 ..... (22 times the 0x00). This kind of looks like a pascal style string, where the first byte contains the string length.

There's no need to define strings like that.

db 13, 10 simply means the bytes "0x0d" and "0x0a".